# Git fu: identify commit(s) that are "behind its remote counterpart"

Tags: git, heroku, diff, commit, git-push

This should be an easy one:

I am trying to push a branch (master) into production on Heroku:

```
$ git push production
To git@heroku.com:my-app.git
 ! [rejected]        master -> master (non-fast-forward)
error: failed to push some refs to 'git@heroku.com:my-app.git'
hint: Updates were rejected because the tip of your current branch is behind
hint: its remote counterpart. Integrate the remote changes (e.g.
hint: 'git pull ...') before pushing again.
```

I realize that this means that code in remote repository is "newer" than code in my local repo.  The recommendation is to `git pull ...` but this is a Heroku repo that we only push to.

I also realize that I can `push -f` to force the change but I want to understand why git is throwing this message, especially because this is a production deploy.

So, I'd like to dig in and understand what Git thinks is wrong... How can I tell which commit(s) are missing locally? When I diff local master against production master I see see the dozens (hundreds?) of diff lines I'm about to push. What I want to see is what git *thinks* exists on production/master that doesn't exist locally.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suspect you have a basic misconception or two here that's leading you in the wrong direction.  In git, a commit is simply an object identifying some particular version of the source tree (well, along with the usual commit message and a list of parent commit IDs; the last are important in that they are how git constructs the "commit graph"—which leads to "branches" below).

What this means, in particular, is that a *commit* is not "ahead" or "behind" anything else.  It's just there, or not there: that's all it can be, present or absent.

Within git—and obviously this is exposed through heroku—there is also the concept of a "branch".  This term is unfortunately rather heavily overloaded.  It can refer to one (or more) of these:

- a subset of the commit graph (a "DAGlet")
- a branch label name
- a "remote branch" label

See also [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25068543/1256452) for more, and some nice graphics illustrating how branch labels point to parts of the commit graph that git constructs based on the parent commit IDs stored in each branch-tip commit.

It's these branch *labels* that are "ahead" and/or "behind" their remote counterparts.

In this case, you have a shared remote repository on your heroku server (which you have called `production`: that's a "remote name", not a branch name).  You also have your own local repository on your local machine (and your collaborators have *their* own local repositories on their machines, all separate from the single shared heroku repository).  When some collaborator, let's call him Bob just for convenience, makes some change(s) and pushes, he gives his commit(s) to the shared repository—but *you* don't have them, you only have *your* commits: all the ones you shared earlier, plus some new one(s) you just made that are not yet shared.

So, now Bob has made some new commit(s) and pushed them successfully.  Now his repo and the shared repo have mostly the same commits you have, plus his new one(s).  You don't have *those* new ones, but you do have your own new one(s).  That is, you have something like this:

```
A <- B <- C <- D <- F   <-- master
```

Here `master` is a *branch label*. and `A` through `F` (note that I skipped `E`; we'll see why in just a moment) are short for the 40-character SHA-1 commit IDs that you see if you run `git log`.  I've drawn backward-pointing arrows between each commit because each commit records its parent ID (by 40-character SHA-1 number), so we can say that each commit "points to" its own parent.

Bob and heroku have this instead:

```
A <- B <- C <- D <- E   <-- master
```

where `E` is the new commit Bob pushed.

Git does not know or really care about Bob (and you don't really have to care either), all it knows at the time you do `git push` is that it calls up heroku on the Internet-phone, sends over your commit `F`, and then asks heroku's git to point the label `master` to commit `F`.

If the heroku-side git does that, the remote repository will wind up having the same commit chain that you have, where `F` points back to `D`, which points back to `C`, and so on.  Commit `E` no longer has anyone pointing to it, so it gets lost.  That's what the remote (heroku) git is telling your git, and your git is then telling you: there is at least one commit that would be lost if the remote made the change your git is asking it to make (or, with `--force`, your git would command it to make).

(Note that even if the heroku git loses this commit, *Bob*'s git is not affected: he will still have his commit `E`.  But this means you'd be forcing Bob to restore his work, perhaps by telling the heroku git to forget yours again and use his instead.  That's no way to collaborate. :-) )

---

As for what to do about it, you have two (or three depending on how you count) choices:

- run roughshod over Bob: wipe out his commit with a force push
- collaborate: merge or rebase your work into / atop Bob's

(if you split the last into "merge with" as one option, and "rebase onto" as a second, you get three choices).

Both "collaborate" options require that you pick up Bob's commit.  You could get it from Bob, but it's easier, at this point, to get it from heroku.  To do that, you start with `git fetch production`: this obtains all the commits that heroku has that you don't—which in this case means commit `E`—and copies them to your own local repository, putting them on a "remote branch".  (Side note: you may be able to run just `git fetch`, without the remote name, or `git fetch --all`; I'm using the remote name here to make things explicit, and because you used it in the `git push` command.)

Because you've named the heroku remote git `production`, the name of this "remote branch" label—which is actually local to your repository (in classic git-confuses-everyone style :-) )—will be `production/master`.  In your repository, we can then draw a more-complete picture of the commit graph:

```
                   F   <-- master
                 /
A <- B <- C <- D
                 \
                   E   <-- production/master
```

You now have both labels pointing to the two commits that diverge from the common branch-ancestry ("DAGlet") of commits `A` through `D`.

It's at this point that you must decide whether to "merge" (make a new commit with *two* parents, to preserve the divergent history) or "rebase" (alter the history, copying your old commit `F` to a new one that's basically the same idea as `F`, but has as its parent, commit `E` instead of commit `D`).  There's a lot of philosophical argument over which way is the right way, but for now let's just say "rebase is the right way", and illustrate the rebase, which you could do by running `git rebase production/master`.

To do the rebase, what git does is compare your original commit `F` to its parent `D` to see what you chagned.  Then it checks out commit `E,` makes the *same* change you made before, and makes a new commit `F'` with the same *message* you wrote before as well:

```
                   F
                 /
A <- B <- C <- D
                 \
                   E - F'
```

I've taken the labels off here on purpose, because right after making that new commit, git does one last thing: it erases your `production` label (which pointed to `F`) and draws a new `production` pointing to the copy, `F'`, which is otherwise the same as `F`.  Now that you can't see the original, we can erase it, straighten out the downward kink in the graph, and draw this new graph:

```
A <- B <- C <- D <- E <- F'
```

There's no reason to call it `F'` any more either, so now we just call it `F`, and put the labels back on:

```
A <- B <- C <- D <- E <- F   <-- master, production/master
```

(both labels now point to `F`).  It now looks as though you never wrote your original `F`; it looks instead like you waited for Bob to finish his work and then wrote your commit `F` based on Bob's latest.  And, now you can push your commit `F` to the heroku remote, because `F`'s parent commit is `E`, so if you get that git to make *its* `master` point to `F`, it won't lose any commits this time.

---

Those two steps—`git fetch production`, then `git rebase production/master`—can be done with a single git command, namely `git pull --rebase production master`.  (Confusingly—user confusion is a pattern with git—this does not use the remote branch label `production/master` anywhere.  When you use the two separate commands, though, you *must* use the remote branch label with the slash in it.)  I often prefer the two separate commands, because that means you can see what happened *before* you start the rebase.

Once you've done the fetch (but neither a merge nor a rebase), to *see* what they have that you don't, or vice versa, give `git log` an extra argument:

```
$ git log master..origin/master
```

or:

```
$ git log origin/master..master
```

This double-dot syntax tells git "find commits starting with the label on the right and working back through the commit graph, but then *don't* show commits that are found by starting with the label on the left."  Let's go back to the intermediate graph again:

```
                   F   <-- master
                 /
A <- B <- C <- D
                 \
                   E   <-- production/master
```

If we start at `production/master`, we get commit `E`.  Working backwards from there we get `D`, then `C`, and on on.  Starting from `master`, we get `F`, then `D`, then `C`, and so on.  Hence `master..production/master` says "show E, but then don't show D or C or any of those earlier commits": they're all reachable by working back from `F`.  So that shows us what we picked up from the remote git, without showing us what we already had before then.  In particular, it shows the commits that our master is "behind" on, which is the ones that they're "ahead".

If you reverse the left and right sides of the two dots, `production/master..master`, that tells git to select the commits on `master` that aren't on `production/master`.  This is where our master is "ahead", or theirs is "behind".

**Summary: use `git fetch` and then the double dot syntax to see what you have that they don't, and vice versa.  Use `git rebase` to copy what you have onto the end of what they have.**

Comment: This is super helpful. Thanks!! Using the double-dot log trick `git log master..production/master` got me the missing commit which I then `git diff 18e8a83b^ 18e8a83b` to see the diff of. Now here's the weird thing. The code from the diff is already in `origin/master` and my local `master`. Unless I'm getting the `+` and `-` confused in my diff?!?

Comment: OK, it looks like the dev who did this pushed these changes to `origin/master` but it has a different commit hash.  Seems like `push --force` would be quickest way to fix. Is there another option worth investigating?

Comment: Probably one of the best explained answers I have seen in a long time. Way to go @torek.

Comment: @Meltemi: I can't tell myself, but I'll note that the suffix-hat syntax (`18e8a83b^`) uses the *first* parent, which only matters if it's a merge (a commit with 2+ parents).  Meanwhile, you might get that effect (of seeing the same diff, of a commit you already have but yours has a different hash) if *someone else* force-pushed a rebase after you'd picked up their changes.  In that case you might want to eliminate your own duplicate of the changes, which you can do with your own rebase.  This can get a bit more complex so I don't want to attempt to put it all in a comment.

Comment: @torek: thanks for your help! You should write a book. I'd buy it! ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Has someone else in your group pushed in the mean time, so you are behind the Heroku repo because of that? Can you try to "git fetch origin --dry-run" to see what it would get? If you git fetch the origin/master" and pull in just the new changes onto origin/master, you can do a git log to list the difference between the tip of origin/master and your local tracking master branch to see the delta, something like "git log origin/master --not master"

Comment: There are three branches in question: my local `master`, `origin/master` and `production/master`. The local `master` and `origin/master` are in sync. It's when I try to push local `master` to `production/master` that I get the error. How can I see what is on production/master but for some reason not in `origin/master` (our workflow shouldn't allow production to get ahead of origin/master but git thinks it has so I want to identify the issue?

Comment: Maybe this will help… what I don't want to see is all the commits on `origin/master` that I'm trying to push to  `production/master`. I only want to see what, if anything, is on `production/master` but not yet on `origin/master`.

Comment: Thanks to @torek's excellent write-up I think I've found my answer: `git log master..production/master`. And this did identify one commit that appears to not be in `origin/master` so some dev made a mistake…

Comment: Yup, basically what I was saying except @torek's write up was excellent.